# Non.exhaustive pattern

Tags: haskell

So im creating a function that says true if a is equal to the fst element of any pair in a list

```
 elemMSet :: Eq a => a -> [(a,Int)] -> Bool
 elemMset a [] = False
 elemMSet a ((t,q):xs)| a==t = True
                      | otherwise = elemMSet a xs
```

I dont undertstand why, it shows an error of non-exhaustive pattern when i try something that should give False like :

```
    elemMSet 'd' [('b',2), ('a',4), ('c',1)]
```

Error:

```
  Tseis.hs:(4,1)-(5,48): Non-exhaustive patterns in function elemMSet
```

Comment: Since you don't care about the `Int` value of each tuple, you can just define the function in terms of `elem` and `map`: `elemMSet a xs = elem a (map fst xs)`. (Increasingly point-free versions would be `elemMSet a = elem a . map fst` and `elemMSet = (. map fst) . elem`.)

Answer (score 3):

You misspelled the function name on line 2, so `elemMSet` only covers the non-empty case. Change the name on line 2 to `elemMSet` (with a capital S) and it will work fine.

Comment: Compiler warning will catch these sorts of issues, I strongly suggest you turn them on (`-Wall`) and pay attention to them.

Comment: where do i put -wall?

Comment: It's uppercase W and it's a command-line option used when you compile the script. Supposed you're using `ghc` to compile a script called elem.hs. Then you'll want to enter `ghc -Wall elem.hs` at your console/shell prompt. However, `-Wall` is from `-W` which supplies various warning. However, you may find `-Wall` to be tad annoying because it prompts you to add extra safeguards, mostly notably type signatures to all your functions.

Comment: In ghci you do `:set -Wall`